# im using vs 2010 and want to using SMSS 2017 just for open bak from newer ver but "Cannot find one or more components"

Tags: sql-server

im using vs 2010 and 2008 sqlexpress, but i need SMSS 2017 just for open bak from newer versio n of sql, because im using 2008 so icant open it. 
got error“Cannot find one or more components”